# Face API: Person number reached subscription level limit

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I tested Face API for identify some persons in large set of images and as a result of experiments I received the following exception:

```
Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException occurred
  ErrorCode=QuotaExceeded
  ErrorMessage=Person number reached subscription level limit.
Parameter name: personCount
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Выдано исключение типа "Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceAPIException".
  Source=Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face
  StackTrace:
       в Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient.<SendRequestAsync>d__60`2.MoveNext()
    --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       в Microsoft.ProjectOxford.Face.FaceServiceClient.<CreatePersonAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
    --- Конец трассировка стека из предыдущего расположения, где возникло исключение ---
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
       в System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
       в FaceMatcher.Microsoft.FaceAPI.MSFTClient.<CreatePersonAsync>d__4.MoveNext() в C:\DevProjects\15SOF\15sof-web-services\FaceMatcher.Microsoft.FaceAPI\MSFTClient.cs:строка 61
  InnerException:
```

I used Face API methods:

- Create Person Group
- Create Person
- Add Face
- Train Person Group
- Delete Person Group

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, I found an answer in Face API Reference:
https://dev.projectoxford.ai/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523c

> Person number reached subscription level limit or person group level
>   limit. Maximum person count per person group is 1000, and maximum
>   person count per subscription is 1000, too.

Then found all groups by "List Person Groups" method and deleted by "Delete a Person Group"